# "Einzig schöne Mädchen" oder "einzige schöne Mädchen"?

Tags: word-usage, difference

In einem Buch, das ich momentan lese, steht:

> Sie war das einzig schöne Mädchen in San Lorenzo.

Warum steht in diesem Fall "einzig" statt "einzige"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nach einem Blick auf [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/einzig) scheint das die adverbielle Nutzung von *einzig* zu sein. Dort gibt es weitere Beispiele:

> die einzig autorisierte Übersetzung
> die einzig zuverlässige Methode
> der einzig mögliche Weg

Answer (score -1):

Wahrscheinlich handelt es sich um einen Schreibfehler.

Geht man davon aus, dass es Absicht ist, würde *einzig* sich auf *schön* beziehen. Dass jemand *einzig schön* ist, würde also ausdrücken, dass es sich um einzigartige Schönheit handelt. (Eine analoge Konstruktion findet man einem Slangausdruck, der in meiner Jugend üblich war: man sagte, jemand sei "selten dämlich". Damit drückte man nicht aus, dass er nur gelegentlich dämlich war, sondern dass er von einer seltenen, also besonders großen Dämlichkeit war.)

Zu dieser Lesart steht aber die Verwendung des bestimmten Artikels im Widerspruch -- denn der zeigt ja an, dass es sich um genau die eine Person aus San Lorenzo handelt, auf die dieses Attribut zutrifft. Es ist aber unklar, warum es in San Lorenzo überhaupt ein Mädchen von einzigartiger Schönheit geben sollte. Und auch nicht, warum es nur genau eine Person geben soll, auf die das Attribut zutrifft.

Das spricht dafür, dass es eigentlich

> Sie war das einzige schöne Mädchen in San Lorenzo.

heißen soll.